# The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, smtpclient

i know this is a duplicate question but all that i have goggled have the same error even though they says when they tried at their solution it goes ok. but mine is like hell. i tried all things, setting `UseDefaultCredentials` to false and setting `EnableSsl` to true, and tried all the ports and disabling the firewall but i failed. please help here's my code:

```
        Credentials c = new Credentials();

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(c.username, c.password);

        client.Port = 25;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        mail.From = new MailAddress(c.username);
        mail.To.Add(c.username);
        mail.Subject = "test";
        mail.Body = "test";
        client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: by the way my 'Credential' Class is my own class.

Comment: gmail uses port 587 with TLS/SSL required

Comment: again, i tried all the ports but still got this error